# Reloading the content of a yesod website with SIGUSR1

Tags: haskell, reload, githooks, yesod

To reload the content of the yesodweb.com website, a reload route has been added. Anybody can initiate a reload by using wget with POST. This does not seem really secure.

Would it be possible to initiate a reload with a git hook instead? Pushing new content to the server would trigger a reload of the blog content etc.

I was thinking of installing a SIGUSR1 handler instead of listening to a specific route. Would this be doable, or would there be a risk of some sort of race condition? If this is doable, where should I add my handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally would stick with the POST, and just add some security to it by requiring a specific token or listening only for specific IP addresses. The reason I haven't bothered is because there's not too much of an attack vector in this reload route: all it can trigger is a git pull from a hard-coded repo that the user can't affect.

If you want to go the signal route, have a look at the `unix` package's [`System.Posix.Signals`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/unix/2.6.0.0/doc/html/System-Posix-Signals.html) module. I'd add the code to `makeApplication` most likely.